# How to ask managers for recommendation for a full-time job at the company that services the company I am interning with?

Tags: job-offer, internship

The company I am currently interning with does not seem to hire entry-level candidates directly into corporate roles.

However, there is a company that services my company (e.g. provides IT support). This service company does seem to accept more entry-level employees and is owned by the same major parent firm.

I have read a ton of articles about how I should go about asking my managers, who I am friendly with, for a potential full-time offer. But I am in a peculiar situation, as I am interested in working for the services company, but do not know how to ask my current managers for a potential recommendation as it might look like I am not interested in my current team. I am afraid of asking people from the services company I know either as word may get back to my team and they might think I went around their backs.

Is there something I can do or some way I can phrase my explanation to my managers to still retain their positive opinions of me while receiving some kind of recommendation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the situation is as you describe it, then the very way you have expressed your goal in your question is a good blueprint for a conversation towards achieving it.

I would suggest that you seek an opportunity for an informal discussion with one of your supervisors.  Start by saying how much you have enjoyed your internship, and then raise the subject of your future plans.  At that point you could ask a question intended to confirm your impression that they do not directly hire entry level candidates, then one to see if they agree that a role might exist for you with the subcontractor.

If they seem to agree with your general impression, and to be happy with your work, then asking if they would be comfortable making an introduction or recommendation would be quite natural.

Or if you are uncomfortable asking for a recommendation, you could ask if they see any reason why it would be *inappropriate* for you to apply to the subcontractor - which could lead them to volunteer a recommendation, or explain any potential contract issue which might make such a transfer impermissible or something that would require specific waiver of a contract term that might otherwise prevent the subcontractor from hiring someone who is (or recently was) technically an employee (if only an intern) of the current company.

It's also entirely possible that while they do not normally hire entry level candidates, they might make an exception and hire you.  By first asking them to confirm that they have such a policy, you implicitly give them an opportunity to consider making an exception, which should smooth over any feelings of disloyalty that might result from your direct pursuit of an opportunity with the subcontractor.

Comment: That is a very thoughtful answer and will help with my talk with my boss next week. Thank you very much for your help!